# Laplace Series for $\frac{\cos\phi}{\sin\theta}$

Tags: fourier-series, spherical-harmonics

I have to solve Poisson equation with source part containing unknown function, and it comes to be, that for doing that I need to calculate Laplace Series (expansion of function in terms of spherical harmonics) coefficients for following function:

$f(\theta, \phi) = \frac{\cos\phi}{\sin\theta}$

Tried to compute it in Wolfram Mathematica but got "Indetermined" for all coefficients with $m=1$ and zero for non-unit $m$.

The exact form for coefficients is as follows:

$f_{lm}=\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(\theta,\phi)Y_{lm}^{*}(\theta,\phi)\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$

I would appreciate if someone could provide an analytical expression for $f_{lm}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have for a normalization $N_{l,m}$ (according to what you use)
$$
f_{l,m}=N_{l,m}\int^{\pi}_{0}\int^{2\pi}_{0}\frac{\cos(\phi)}{\sin(\theta)}\sin(\theta)e^{im\phi}P^{m}_l(\cos(\theta))d\theta d\phi=
$$
$$
=N_{l,m}\left(\int^{\pi}_0\cos(\phi)e^{im\phi}d\phi\right)\left(\int^{2\pi}_{0}P^l_m(\cos(\theta))d\theta\right),
$$
where $P^l_m(x)$ is the associated Legendre polynomial.
The first integral is (easily)
$$
\int^{\pi}_0\cos(\phi)e^{im\phi}d\phi=\frac{i(1+e^{i\pi m})m}{m^2-1}
$$
with $m$ integer.

For the second integral is
$$
P^m_l(z)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-m)}\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)^{m/2}{ }_2F_1\left(-l,1+l;1-m;\frac{1-z}{2}\right).
$$
Hence
$$
P^m_l(\cos(\theta))=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-m)}\left(\frac{1+\cos(\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)}\right)^{m/2}{ }_2F_1\left(-l,1+l;1-m;\frac{1-\cos(\theta)}{2}\right)=
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-m)}\left(\frac{2\cos^2(\theta/2)}{2\sin^2(\theta/2)}\right)^{m/2}{ }_2F_1\left(-l,1+l;1-m;\frac{2\sin^2(\theta/2)}{2}\right)=
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-m)}\left(\cot^2(\theta/2)\right)^{m/2}{ }_2F_1\left(-l,1+l;1-m;\sin^2(\theta/2)\right)=
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-m)}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-l)_n(l+1)_n}{(1-m)_n n!}\left(\cot^2(\theta/2)\right)^{m/2}\left(\sin^{2}(\theta/2)\right)^n.
$$
Hence
$$
\int^{2\pi}_{0}P^m_l(\cos(\theta))d\theta=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-m)}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-l)_n(l+1)_n}{(1-m)_n n!}\int^{2\pi}_{0}\left(\cos^2(\theta/2)\right)^{m/2}\left(\sin^{2}(\theta/2)\right)^{n-m/2}d\theta
$$ 
But $\cos(x)$ is monotone in $(0,\pi)$ and a simple change of variable $\theta/2\rightarrow \theta $ in the above integral lead us to
$$
I_{n,m}=\int^{2\pi}_{0}\left(\cos^2(\theta/2)\right)^{m/2}\left(\sin^{2}(\theta/2)\right)^{n-m/2}d\theta=2\int^{\pi}_0\left(\cos^2(\theta)\right)^{m/2}\left(\sin^{2}(\theta)\right)^{n-m/2}d\theta
$$
Another change of variable $cos(\theta)\rightarrow t$ lead us to
$$
I_{n,m}=2\int^{-1}_{1}(t^2)^{m/2}(1-t^2)^{n-m/2}\frac{-dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}
=2\int^{1}_{-1}(t^2)^{m/2}(1-t^2)^{n-m/2-1/2}dt=
$$
$$
=4\int^{1}_{0}(t^2)^{m/2}(1-t^2)^{n-m/2-1/2}dt=2\int^{1}_{0}t^{m/2-1/2}(1-t)^{n-m/2-1/2}dt.
$$
Hence
$$
I_{n,m}=2\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1+m}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1-m}{2}+n\right)}{n!}
$$
Hence
$$
\int^{2\pi}_{0}P^{m}_{l}(\cos(\theta))d\theta=\frac{2}{\Gamma(1-m)}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-l)_n(1+l)_n}{(1-m)_n(n!)^2}\Gamma\left(\frac{1+m}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1-m}{2}+n\right)=
$$
$$
=\frac{2}{\Gamma(1-m)}\Gamma\left(\frac{1+m}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1-m}{2}\right)\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-l)_n(1+l)_n}{(1-m)_n(n!)^2}\left(\frac{1-m}{2}\right)_n.
$$
And finaly for $l,m$ integers with $l\geq0$, we have 
$$
f_{l,m}=N_{l,m}\frac{(1+e^{i\pi m})m}{1-m^2}\frac{2i\Gamma\left(\frac{1-m}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1+m}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(1-m)}{ }_3F_2\left(-l,l+1,\frac{1-m}{2};1-m,1;1\right)
$$
But according to Mathematica program (and I think it must be on tables)
$$
\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-m)}{ }_3F_2\left(-l,l+1,\frac{1-m}{2};1-m,1;1\right)=\frac{2^m\pi}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1-l}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(1+\frac{l}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1-l-m}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(1+\frac{l-m}{2}\right)}
$$
and
$$
N_{l,m}:=\sqrt{\frac{2l+1}{4\pi}}\sqrt{\frac{(l-m)!}{(l+m)!}}
$$ 
Hence for $l,m$ integers and $l\geq 0$, we have
$$
f_{l,m}=4\pi iN_{l,m}\frac{2^me^{i\pi m/2}m}{(m^2-1)\Gamma\left(\frac{1-l}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(1+\frac{l}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1-l-m}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(1+\frac{l-m}{2}\right)}
$$
For $l\leq-1$ we set in the above formula $l\rightarrow -l-1$.

Comment: Oh. Hypergeometric function always looked like some scary monster for me :D Thanks for the thorough answer.